# Matlab: multidimensional array for images

Tags: arrays, image, matlab, image-processing, multidimensional-array

I am new to the concept of multi-dimensional array and I am trying to apply it to the following image that I have:

[image]

What I would like to do is to create a 5D array as follow [number of boxes in a row, number of boxes in a column, size of each box in x, size of each box in y, RGB] in this example it would be [8, 8, 200, 200, 3].

I have written the following code to grab the pixels of the top left box (the red one) (just to test it):

```
Image = imread('Grid.jpg');
img = zeros(8, 8, 200, 200, 3)
img(1, 1, 1:200, 1:200, :) = Image(1:200, 1:200, :);
imshow(squeeze(img(1,1,:,:,:)))
```

When I run the code I only get a yellow line.
Could somebody please point out what am I doing wrong and why I am getting the result I am getting now?

Comment: Initialize your `img` as `uint8`, e.g. `img = uint8(zeros(8, 8, 200, 200, 3))`, and it should work.

Comment: I could run your example only by changing the filename of the picture to `QZiuc.jpg` and looking at the data from `img(1,1,:,:,:)` it only contains the red box from the left top corner of your picture. This means, line 1-3 of your code seem to be okay.

Comment: As an addition: The "problem" is you're using `imshow` with `double` "images". [Here](https://mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/88934-images-don-t-show-with-imshow-after-converting-them-to-double#answer_98479) is a concise explanation. I didn't want to copy it.

Comment: @HansHirse is right and I think that using `uint8(your_image)` is the best solution. But `imshow` also support values in the range [0 1]. So `imshow(squeeze(img(1,1,:,:,:))/255)` will also work.

Comment: Both initialising the image as uint8 and dividing by 255 solved the issue. Thank you